# Grunt Compass Fatal error: spawn EPERM

Tags: ruby, node.js, gruntjs, compass-sass

I have recently been trying to work with **[this](https://github.com/dwightjack/grunt-email-boilerplate)** recently, originally i had issues with ruby etc, then i uninstalled ruby and went with the rvm way of doing ruby and now i no longer have those problems..

And now hopefully i have my last issue, which seems to be a grunt/grunt-contrib-compass issue.

I get the following error when i try to run any of the commands that involve the compass task:

```
Running "compass:dev" (compass) task
Verifying property compass.dev exists in config...OK
File: [no files]
Options: config="C:\\code\\newsletters\\globalgeorgia\\test\\grunt-email-boilerplate\\vendor\\compass-config.rb", cssDir="tmp/css", imagesDir="tmp/images"
Fatal error: spawn EPERM
```

And I have tried solutions around similar issues with no luck... Any Help Would be Great!

**UPDATE**

Ive figured that it has to be with compass because **[this](https://github.com/happymedium/responsive-email-kit)** gives the exact same issue where as **[this](https://github.com/leemunroe/grunt-email-design)** (not using compass) works perfectly.

Comment: Serious question: are you running any anti-virus software on your windows machine?

Comment: That usually is the culprit of an `EPERM` error in windows.

Comment: ah i see, thanks anyways, im trying to install a -pre version of compass now.. having compile issues with fii, so updating gcc libraries in cygwin in hope of some magical result

Comment: @DawidvanderHoven I have the exact same issue right now. Did you find a solution to this? My compass throws "spawn EPERM"

Comment: @luuksen i never did find an solution, as i have switched to osx and everything works beatifully now.